# Fetch exif(image_metadata) for images from cloudinary using nodejs

Tags: node.js, image, metadata, exif, cloudinary

I tried to fetch the list of images in cloudinary with the help of API. I'm getting the image details other than exif(image_metadata). Help me to fetch the exif(image_metadata).

The below is the code which I used to fetch the details:

```
 try {
    let result = cloudinary.v2.api.resources({ image_metadata: true }, 
function(
      error,
      result
    ) {
      console.log("result", result);
      if (result) {
        successCB(result);
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    failureCB(err);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a method that will return only the metadata. You will need to parse this on your own end.

You can retrieve the image metadata by using the image_metadata parameter when uploading when using the explicit method. For example,

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.explicit("sample",{type: "upload", image_metadata:true}, function(err, res){console.log(err, res); })
```

Comment: I can fetch the value for the image whose public_id includes sample. But I can't fetch for all the images by providing like this   
cloudinary.v2.uploader.explicit(
      { type: "upload", image_metadata: true },
      function(error, result) {
        console.log("result", result);
        if (result) {
          successCB(result);
        }
      }